# Resizing the superview according to the subviews

Tags: autolayout

I have 3 subviews(`UILabel`, `UIImageview`, `UIButton`) to be laid out on a container view. All the subviews are laid out using visual format language (VFL). The subview have padding from the leading , top edges etc. The content of the subview are dynamic so their sizes changes all the time. i want to resize the superview(container view) to exactly fit all the subviews. Is this possible by auto layout? i have seen some of the link here which suggest intrinsic size which i am not able to understand. can someone suggest a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. If you plan to resize the superview according to subview content, then intrinsic content size is the way to go.

The ever excellent Ray Wenderlich site has a tutorial that covers this well. It's [Beginning Auto Layout in iOS 6: Part 2/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2):

> Intrinsic Content Size
>
> Before Auto Layout, you always had to tell buttons and other controls
>   how big they should be, either by setting their frame or bounds
>   properties or by resizing them in Interface Builder. But it turns out
>   that most controls are perfectly capable of determining how much space
>   they need, based on their content.
>
> A label knows how wide and tall it is because it knows the length of
>   the text that has been set on it, as well as the font size for that
>   text. Likewise for a button, which might combine the text with a
>   background image and some padding for the rounded corners.
>
> The same is true for segmented controls, progress bars, and most other
>   controls, although some may only have a predetermined height but an
>   unknown width.
>
> This is known as the intrinsic content size, and it is an important
>   concept in Auto Layout. You have already seen it in action with the
>   buttons. Auto Layout asks your controls how big they need to be and
>   lays out the screen based on that information.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

In my case, I wanted to give rounded corners to segmented control. For that, I embedded segmented control in `UIView`. Now I was required to resize that container view as per size of segmented control.

I gave only following constraint and everything was taken care itself.

**(1)** Chose container view and give it `X` and `Y` constraints.

- Leading space to Super view.
- Top space to Super view.

**(2)** Chose container view and give `Leading` | `Trailing` | `Top` | `Bottom` constraint.

- Leading space to segmented control.
- Top space to segmented control.
- Trailing space to segmented control.
- Bottom space to segmented control.

**(3)** Chose segmented control and give it `Height` and `Width` constraints.

- Height : 30   // Whatever
- Width : 250   // Whatever

Now if I change the height and width of my segmented control, it automatically adjust container view's size (super-view of segmented control).